# How to type ASCII code "00" and "01" in linux bash?

Tags: bash, hex, ascii

I have program which looks like this:

```
/* buf_overflow.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char buf[4];
    char exploit_buf[4];
    fgets(buf, 4, stdin);
    gets(exploit_buf);
    printf("exploit_buf: %s\n", exploit_buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm going to use the vulnerability of "gets" function to buffer-overflow some other variables. The value that I want to write to "exploit_buf" is "AAAAAAAA\x01\x00\x00\x00", but i don't know how to send ASCII codes "01" and "00" into exploit_buf.

I know that using this command "printf "AAAAAAAA\x01\x00\x00\x00"" can type the characters that I want, but I don't know how to send them into exploit_buf. I also know that Alt+(number keys on the right of the keyboard) can generate characters from the ASCII code I typed, but this doesn't work in my program either.

The main problem is "how can I skip the first function "fgets()" and type arbitrary ASCII code in "gets()"".

Anyone knows how to type arbitrary ASCII code in the command line of linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `echo -e`:

```
$ echo -ne 'AAAAAAAA\x01\x00\x00\x00' | python -c 'import sys; print repr(sys.stdin.read())'
'AAAAAAAA\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

`-e` allows `echo` to interpret escape codes, and `-n` suppresses the trailing newline.

Note that the Python program prints out the string representation of what it received, which is exactly what we sent in using `echo`.

For more complex exploit strings, it's not uncommon to simply use Perl or Python to build the exploit string directly:

```
$ perl -e 'print "A" x 1024 . "\0\0\0\1"' | ./buf_overflow
```

Comment: youcan also use the BASH built in printf..     printf 'AAAAAAAA\x01\x00\0\0'

Answer (score 9):

Type the following command in terminal.

```
echo $'\000\001' > file1
```

This will save the values of ASCII Character 1 and ASCII Character 2 into a file named file1. Now you can read this in to your buffer exploit_buf.

Comment: but this program would fgets() first and then gets(), how can I skip the first function "fgets()"?

Comment: [Bash’s ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) does also understand other escape sequences like `\xHH`.

Answer (score 0):

Great example from nneonneo.

However if you wish to type them in directly without help from a script you can change your keyboard config to use the "USA International (AltGr dead keys)" mode (under System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout) then you can use special symbols easily by using the right alt button.
Examples -
é is rAlt+e.
° is rAlt-shift-0-0 (press 0 twice while holding the other buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just getting input from standard input, you can just pipe the output of your `printf` into it:

```
printf 'whatever' | myprogram
```